# Order all files by size using find

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, sort, size

As practice I need to complete a script that orders all filles by size with a given extension(.txt for example) including those in subdirectories too.

```
For example; 
./ex1.sh einstein txt
einstein/copyright.txt
einstein/do-how.txt
einstein/etext9/bil11.txt
einstein/etext9/2ws271.txt
einstein/etext9/liber11.txt
einstein/etext0/bib0010h/Readme.txt
einstein/etext0/kknta10.txt
```

I can't use du or other advanced commands. At some point I need to use find, I tried something like this

```
find -depth - type f -name "*.$extension" | sort ....
```

but this hasn't work really well, as i don't really know how to sort them by size, only result i get is sorted by name.

I was looking for an output similar to ls -lhS but including subdirectories.

Comment: If you can only use `find`, why are you using `sort`? Please [edit] your question and explain your requirements. What is your example? Is it the output of a command? Or is it your `ex1.sh` script? If so, what are the parameters (`einstein` and `txt`) that you are giving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` includes an option `-printf` which allows you to format what to output about your results, and how to output them. One of possibilities listed in the documentation for that option (see the `man` page) is `%s` for a file's size in bytes. Thus, you can add to your find command something like `-printf "%s %p\n".

Comment: @terdon - yes. His answer had not been posted when I began writing my answer.

Comment: Ah, the classic race condition! :)

Answer (score 6):

The only sorting that any of the `find`s can do AFAIK is to have contents appear before the containing directory (the `-depth` option). You will have use something else to sort on size.

If you have GNU find, try:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.$extension" -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | sed 's/^[0-9]* //'
```

`-printf "%s %p\n"` prints the size and file path, then we sort numerically, and then strip the size using `sed`.

Comment: (assuming file paths don't contain newlines and bytes not forming valid characters and that `$extension` doesn't contain wildcards)

Comment: (in which case `\0` with `-printf` and the `-z` options as needed, I think)

Comment: yep, NUL terminated output is the solution - e.g. `find . -type f -printf "%s %p\0" | sort -z -k1,1n | awk -v RS='\0' {print $2}'` (non-portable - works with GNU awk, maybe some others).  +1, was going to write an answer like this but you've already written it.

Answer (score 3):

i use

```
   find . -type f -iname "*.$extension" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lS
```

this works fine for me

Comment: Thank you! As macOS is based on BSD, and not GNU, this is the only one of the answers which works in bash on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*.$extension(D.oL)
```

To get a GNU `ls -lh`-type output, with GNU `ls`:

```
ls -Ulhd -- **/*.$extension(D.oL)
```

Or if the list is too large:

```
autoload zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs --eof= -- **/*.$extension(D.oL) '' ls -Ulhd --
```

Or

```
printf '%s\0' **/*.$extension(D.oL) | xargs -r0 ls -Ulhd --
```

If for some reason, you do need to use `find`, you can always do:

```
printf '%s\0' ./**/*.$extension(D.oL) | xargs -r0 sh -c '
  exec find "$@" -prune ...' sh
```

Comment: The OP needs to use `find` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to [muru's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430385/449889)

You can use `-exec du '{}' ';'` inplace of `-printf "%s %p"` and still produces same format.  So the final command be like

```
find . -type f -iname "*.$extension" -exec du '--' '{}' ';' | sort -n | sed 's/^[0-9]* //'
```

Explanation for the `-exec du '-b' '--' '{}' ';'`

1. `-exec` flag tells `find` to execute command (which is `du`) with `{}` occurence in arguments replaced with file path
2. `'-b'` tells `du` command to output bytes amount instead in kilobytes
3. `'--'` is a (flag? I need help about what this named) which signals ends of options and the rest of arguments is positional argument. One example where this needed is doing anything with file ambiguously named as option like `-whatever`
4. `'{}'` going back to point 1. `find` will substitute this with file path
5. `";"` tells for `find` command that arguments for `-exec` is ended and can process the rest of arguments normally